# why $f_n(x)=\frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}$ cannot be dominated for $a\leq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> The question is ask to compute the 
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^{\infty} \frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}dx.$$
>   I know 
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^{\infty} \frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}dx=\begin{cases} 0 &  \text{if }  
>     a>0 \\
>       \frac{\pi}{2} &  \text{if } a=0\\
>      \pi &  \text{if } a<0
>       \end{cases}$$
>   I try to apply the dominated convergence theorem for $f_n(x)=\frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}$ which we have
>   $$
> f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}=\begin{cases} 0 &  \text{if }  
>     x\neq 0 \\
>      \infty &  \text{if } x=0
>       \end{cases} $$
>
> If $a>0$, then $\mid f_n\mid \leq 1/x^2$. So Dominated convergence theorem(DCT) can be applied in this case.

But how to show that  $a\leq 0$ cannot apply the DCT? In other words, why $f_n(x)$ cannot be dominated?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x^2}$ isn't integrable on $[0,\infty)$.  Also, probably an important thing to notice for $a < 0$ is that $f_n$ is an even function.

Comment: @Dzoooks But why isn't there any integrable function on, say, $(0,1)$ which dominates $f_n$?

Comment: @amsmath  I did not say there wasn't!  Reread please.

Comment: But if there would be, then either DCT would be wrong or the thing you know, right? Because suppose there would be such a dominating function and you could apply DCT then the integral would be always $0$, since the integral doesn't care about this one point $x=0$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @hal4math Sure. I think the task is to show the claim without using DCT.

Comment: @Love GQY  Note that an antiderivative is $\arctan(nx)$.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I just want to know how to apply the DCT.

Comment: @LoveGQY As you already noted, you cannot apply the DCT for $a\le 0$.

Comment: @amsmath So how to show that we could not find such dominated $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \leq 0$ and let $g(x) \geq f_n(x)$ for all $n$ and all $x \geq a$.  Then for $x \in \left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right]$, we have $$g\left(x\right) \geq f_n\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{n}{2}.$$

Thus, $$\int_a^{\infty} g(x)dx \geq \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\cdot \frac{n}{2} = \infty,$$ so any dominating $g$ is not integrable on $[a, \infty)$.